# Grapesjs deleting custom tool issue

Tags: javascript, angular, grapesjs

After deleting grapesjs custom tool ( from html editor ) that contain html with Js code , the code still in the grapes editor , how i can remove it ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put settimeout() to make it work correctly.